# using python 2.6?

Tags: python

i have no way of upgrade to python 2.7 or 3.1 so i am stuck with python 2.6 on my ubuntu 10.04 machine.

will i still be able to find host that supports  python 2.6?

is using python 2.6 still consider outdated or bad practice?

Comment: 2.6 and 2.7 are *mostly* compatible - something that runs on 2.6 will most likely run on 2.7 just fine.

Comment: You could try my [build recipe for squeeze](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8931660/350713).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> will i still be able to find host that
>   supports python 2.6?

Yes. No problems whatsoever.

> is using python 2.6 still consider
>   outdated or bad practice?

No, it is not.

**However:**

> I have no way of upgrade to python 2.7

**Yes you do.** You download the source code from www.python.org and install it. 
What you should be careful to do in *not* to overwrite the system Python.

Install it either with "altinstall" (will not override the system python) or even better,
use a custom prefix. For example:

```
$ ./configure --prefix = /opt/python27
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

It is often a good idea to use a separate Python install for development, as you can do whatever you want with it including deleting it and reinstalling it without affecting the system Python.

You are NOT stuck. :)

I'm Using Ubuntu 10.04 as well I have Python 2.3.7, 2.4.6, 2.5.5, 2.6.6, 2.7.1, 3.0.1, 3.1.2 and 3.2b2+ installed. No problems. Yes, I use all of them, even though it's mostly 2.4 and 2.6.

Comment: You answered this question some time ago but may I ask you how to choose what version to use?

Comment: @la_f0ka: You use the latest version of the versions that you can use. Only you know which versions you can use.

Answer (score 4):

2.6 will be around for a long time. There are many machines that still run even 2.4, so you're fine.

Answer (score 3):

Python 2.6 will probably still be around for a while, as Python 2.7 was released only a few months ago.

You can always use `from __future__ import ...` to make use of some of the newer features from Python 3.x

Answer (score 0):

Python3.1 is in the repositories for 10.04

```
$ apt-cache show python3
Package: python3
Priority: optional
Section: python
Installed-Size: 76
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Matthias Klose <doko@debian.org>
Architecture: all
Source: python3-defaults
Version: 3.1.2-0ubuntu1
Depends: python3.1 (>= 3.1.2), python3-minimal (= 3.1.2-0ubuntu1)
Suggests: python3-doc (>= 3.1.2-0ubuntu1), python3-tk (>= 3.1.2-0ubuntu1), python3-profiler (>= 3.1.2-0ubuntu1)
Filename: pool/main/p/python3-defaults/python3_3.1.2-0ubuntu1_all.deb
Size: 11096
MD5sum: 81f3f3bf790f5d7756b76c8d92fcea86
SHA1: 32e12dc7f9500456e063f22645c1cfed76b8845c
SHA256: 0f541352ace2fcf1929a93320ffbe2f1de4e1d140bbe70a7c5a709403b73341c
Description: An interactive high-level object-oriented language (default python3 version)
 Python, the high-level, interactive object oriented language,
 includes an extensive class library with lots of goodies for
 network programming, system administration, sounds and graphics.
 .
 This package is a dependency package, which depends on Debian's default
 Python version (currently v3.1).
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
Supported: 3y
```